# How to draw dynamic html table? The table content should come from WCF web service

Tags: asp.net, wcf, html-table

I want to draw a table dynamically on html page. Number of rows, number of columns, column names, all such data should be returned by a WCF webservice. 
1. How can my webservice serialize and return this data? I have all the required data in dictionaries.
2. How can I render such dynamic table on the html page?

My web service will be giving me the results that I just want to represent in tabular format on the aspx or html page. I will not be dealing with any SQL database tables or rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with learning the basics of WCF. Here are some great resources (including videos) to warm you up:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/first-steps-with-wcf.aspx

Number or rows, number of columns, column names, etc. sounds like you need a DataSet (or a DataTable). DataSets are serializable, and you can return them from your wcf services.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.aspx

You said "web page". You need a web framework. In .Net Asp.Net Web Forms and Asp.Net MVC3 are some examples of frameworks you may use. If this is just a single page, I suggest using a simple aspx page (web form). Otherwise MVC3 is best suited.
Good introduction here: http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_intro.asp

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I am using webforms since it will be just a single page. And my web service will be giving me the results that I just want to represent in tabular format on the aspx or html page. I will not be dealing with any SQL database tables or rows as such. So, in that case, do I need to use DataSet or DataTable? What could be the best solution? Currently I dont use web service and using C# code in codebehind file, I render the table dynamically on aspx page.

Comment: Are you responsible of developing the service or is it an existing service?

Comment: I will be developing the service and aspx page both.

Comment: I mentioned DataSets because you could use a dataset as the return type of your service operation. Your service will create and populate the dataset before returning it to the web page which will display it.

Comment: I generally try to avoid DataSets as they're not (IMO) SOA compliant.  In this case however if the client and the service are both under your control and both are .NET (as the post indicates) it's probably the quickest way to do it, since you appear to be needing to deal with a variable number of rows and columns (plus the column names).  If this is something that you will need to use often, potentially in different applications, you might do better to work on a more elegant solution that would allow reuse across applications and/or non .NET clients.

Comment: Thanks Moussa and Tim. I will go with the dataset.